# How to sort a UDT vector in descending order?

Tags: c++, oop

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class Point
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;

    Point(int x = 0, int y = 0)
    {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
    }

    bool operator>(const Point &p1)
    {
        return (x + y) > (p1.x + p1.y);
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<Point> v = {{1, 2}, {3, 1}, {0, 1}};

    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), greater<Point>());

    for (auto i : v)
        cout << i.x << " " << i.y << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I want to sort a UDT vector in descending order. So I tried to overload the operator > as written in the class. But it's giving me error. What should I do to sort the UDT vector in descending order.

This is the error:

```
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20221128/include/c++/13.0.0/string:49,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20221128/include/c++/13.0.0/bitset:52,
                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20221128/include/c++/13.0.0/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdc++.h:52,
                 from <source>:1:
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20221128/include/c++/13.0.0/bits/stl_function.h: In instantiation of 'constexpr bool std::greater<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = Point]':
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20221128/include/c++/13.0.0/bits/predefined_ops.h:158:30:   required from 'constexpr bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<_Compare>::operator()(_Iterator1, _Iterator2) [with _Iterator1 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Point*, std::vector<Point> >; _Iterator2 = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Point*, std::vector<Point> >; _Compare = std::greater<Point>]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20221128/include/c++/13.0.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1819:14:   required from 'void std::__insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Point*, vector<Point> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<greater<Point> >]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20221128/include/c++/13.0.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1859:25:   required from 'void std::__final_insertion_sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Point*, vector<Point> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<greater<Point> >]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20221128/include/c++/13.0.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1950:31:   required from 'void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Point*, vector<Point> >; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_comp_iter<greater<Point> >]'
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20221128/include/c++/13.0.0/bits/stl_algo.h:4893:18:   required from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter, _Compare) [with _RAIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Point*, vector<Point> >; _Compare = greater<Point>]'
<source>:27:9:   required from here
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20221128/include/c++/13.0.0/bits/stl_function.h:398:20: error: no match for 'operator>' (operand types are 'const Point' and 'const Point')
  398 |       { return __x > __y; }
      |                ~~~~^~~~~
<source>:17:10: note: candidate: 'bool Point::operator>(const Point&)' (near match)
   17 |     bool operator>(const Point &p1)
      |          ^~~~~~~~
<source>:17:10: note:   passing 'const Point*' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers
```

Comment: What error is the compiler giving you? Most often, error fixing starts by understanding what the error at hand is.

Comment: What is a "UDT" in this context? (And please be more specific than "it's giving me error".)

Comment: Why are you using these : `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`  `using namespace std;`? You should include `<vector>` and `<algorithm>`. And you should not be using namespace std;

Comment: Sorry for not adding the error, because it was very long error so I thought no would read it. But the answer given by @Rulle solved my issue. Thanks everyone for your time.

Comment: This error `passing 'const Point*' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers` is what should give the clue (for future reference).

Comment: Wherever you learned `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, block that website in your browser and never go there again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the word `const` to your `operator>` method so that its signature becomes

```
bool operator>(const Point &p1) const
```

instead of

```
bool operator>(const Point &p1)
```

Adding `const` to this method means that you inform the compiler that the method won't modify the object that the method is associated with. That is required because `greater` expects the objects being compared to be constant.